# How do I set up Ubuntu 15.10 so I can Filezilla from my windows 10 desktop and create/remove/add files to my server

Tags: server, apache2, ftp

I have a separate server set up with Ubuntu server 15.10.
I can connect from my windows 10 desktop using Filezilla but I can't upload anything to my `/var/www/html` folder for working on websites I create.

**How do I set up Ubuntu 15.10 so I can Filezilla from my windows 10 desktop and create/remove/add files to my server?**

I already tried seting up my html folder with `chmod 777` but still can't write to it via sftp.
Here's a sample of what I get:

```
Command:    put "C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\Drupal updates\modules\devel\devel_generate\tests\modules\devel_generate_example\src\Plugin\DevelGenerate\ExampleDevelGenerate.php" "/var/www/html/learningdrupal8/modules/devel/devel_generate/tests/modules/devel_generate_example/src/Plugin/DevelGenerate/ExampleDevelGenerate.php"
Error:  /var/www/html/learningdrupal8/modules/devel/devel_generate/tests/modules/devel_generate_example/src/Plugin/DevelGenerate/ExampleDevelGenerate.php: open for write: no such file or directory
Error:  File transfer failed
Status: Disconnected from server
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this link
[share between windows and linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/)